# correct use of single/double pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I am doing a university project where i want to read lines from a file and store them in an array of Records, (and later sort them) each record is a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct Record{
    int id; 
    char* string_field;
    int int_field;
    double double_field;
} Record;
```

The size of the array is unknown. Initially im allocating a portion in memory as follows and calling a function to load the Records from file in my Records Array, and then reallocating (in the load_array() function) whenever i need more space:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: ordered_array_main <file_name>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
   
    int capacity = 2;
    Record* array_of_records = NULL;
    array_of_records = (Record*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(Record));

    int size = load_array(argv[1], array_of_records, capacity);//size_of_array

    printf("%d, %d\n", (*array_of_records).id, (*array_of_records).int_field); 
    //printing here shows me random garbage values. 
    free(array_of_records);
    return 0;
}
```

The load_array function is as follows, i will skip the part where i do my fopen() and strtok() stuff since its doesnt matter to the issue. I am reading each line and saving 4 variables (id, int_field, string_field, float_field) which then will be stored in each field of the current Record of my Records array.

The issue is that when i print the values of my record array field in the load_array() function they are the correctly read ones from the file, but when i go to print them in the main() they are garbage values, typical C style.
I noticed by printing the array_of_records pointer value at different locations that it changes where i do the realloc(), but as far as i know i dont think i made any mistakes here, realloc is returning me the new location of memory and im storing it in tmp, and then storing tmp in array_of_records.

```
int load_array(const char* file_name, Record* array_of_records, int capacity){
    int index_of_record = 0;
        
    while(fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp)!=NULL){

        int id_field = atoi(field[0]);
        char *string_field = malloc((strlen(field[1])+1)* sizeof(char));
        strcpy(string_field, field[1]);
        int int_field = atoi(field[2]);
        double double_field = atof(field[3]);
        
        if(index_of_record>=capacity){
            Record* tmp = NULL;
            tmp = (Record*)realloc(array_of_records,2*capacity*sizeof(Record));
            if(tmp==NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failure\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            array_of_records = tmp;           
            capacity = 2*capacity;    
        }
        

        (array_of_records+index_of_record)->id = id_field;
        (array_of_records+index_of_record)->string_field = string_field;
        (array_of_records+index_of_record)->int_field = int_field;
        (array_of_records+index_of_record)->double_field = double_field;


        printf("%d\n", (array_of_records+index_of_record)->int_field);
        //printing here shows me the correct values 

        
        index_of_record++;

        free(string_field);

    }
    return index_of_record;
}
```

I cant wrap my head around this issue, it seems that i am passing correctly the pointer of the Record array, and then storing each record moving fowards with index_of_record. I am clueless. Maybe i am supposed to use double pointers?

Comment: c passes all arguments to function by value, including pointers. If you want to modify the `array_of_records` pointer inside `load_array` you need to add another indirection level: make the parameter a `Record**` and pass `&array_of_records` as an argument. You might also want to pass `capacity` by pointer and modify it as well.

Comment: i understand now, i knew that c passed all arguments to a function by value but i completely overlooked that in this situation. Thanks to your comment i fixed it and it works, thanks a lot!!